# Explicit combinatorial construction minimizing intersection of sets

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms, expanders

I'd like to know if anything is known about the following problem:

Suppose we choose positive integer $t$ to be constant. Let $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, where $n$ is sufficiently large. Consider a partition $A_j$ of $S$ of the form $S = A_{j,1} \cup S_{j,2} \cup \dots \cup S_{j,\sqrt{n}}$, where each $S_{j,i}$ is roughly of size $\sqrt{n}$. Is it possible to find an explicit construction of $k = O(1)$ such partitions ($k$ not depending on $n$ or $t$), say $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k$, such that for any choice of $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_{t/10}$ (for each $i \leq k$), we have
$|\bigcap_{i=1}^k (A_{i,i_1} \cup A_{i,i_2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{i,i_{t/10}})| = O(t)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question refers to t/10 but does not seem to refer to t itself, so I wonder if there is a typo in your formulation....